# How to hide photos that I put into an album from the "All Items" view in the Photos app?

Tags: photos, photos.app, photo-stream

Is there a way to not show photos that I have placed in certain albums in the Photos app?

My logic is - I want to sort some photos by albums and hide them from the "All Items" view because they become a mess for me since I have already sorted them into certain albums.

In the main "All Items" view, I would like to show only photos and videos that have not been placed in any album.